# I want to update the data from server by giving a time limit

Tags: android, database

I want to update the data from server for every 15 min using time scheduling.  Is there a way, so we can update the data background?

Answer (score 1):

Use the alarm manager set it to send a broadcast to wake up your intentservice instance every 15 mins and do the update from there.

Edit:

I added the boot complete way of doing it for your convenience, you might want to start the alarm thing upon opening your app. Either way just follow the codes where alarm manager and intent service are.

First off create a broadcast receiver that listens for the boot complete

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.example.CheckUpdateIntentService;

public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //Create pending intent to trigger when alarm goes off
        Intent i = new Intent(context, CheckUpdateIntentService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Set an alarm to trigger the pending intent in intervals of 15 minutes
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //Trigger the alarm starting 1 second from now
        long triggerAtMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 1000;
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Now for the intent service to do the actual updates

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.IntentService;

public class CheckUpdateIntentService extends IntentService {

    public CheckUpdateIntentService()
    {
        super(CheckUpdateIntentService.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        //Actual update logic goes here
        //Intent service itself is already a also a Context so you can get the context from this class itself
        Context context = CheckUpdateIntentService.this;
        //After updates are done the intent service will shutdown itself and wait for the next interval to run again
    }
}
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml add the following items:

Permission to receive the boot complete broadcast

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Then in the application tags add the BootCompleteReceiver you have created with the corresponding intent filter you are interested in, and of course the intentservice component

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".CheckUpdateIntentService" ></service>
```

This is a very skeletal implementation, you can try it out first if you need more help, let us know.

Comment: Can I get some tutorial or any source code on how to set alarm manager for every 15 min and send it to receiver and update data from server?

Comment: thank you! But I do not see any output. I am implementing same code and onHandleIntent method passing a toast message to check if its working or not, am I doing anything wrong? I wanted to test it

Comment: Debug the app? Write something to the db..It runs on another thread not the ui thread a toast can't be shown from there directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345682/time-scheduling-by-using-alarm-manager

Comment: Please find my question in the above link